# Proving that a complex-valued function is well-defined and analytic in a ball

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am trying to practice for one of my exams for my complex analysis finals, and came across this question. I am lost and really need help with answering this.

> Suppose $g(z)$ is analytic in the ball centered at $z_0$ with radius $r$, $B(z_0,r)$. For any element $z \in B(z_0,r)$, take the contour $\Gamma(z)$ such that $\Gamma(z)$ lies in the disk $B(z_0,r)$ and $\Gamma(z)$ extends from $z_0$ to $z$. Prove that $f(z) = \int_{\Gamma(z)} g(w) ~ dw$ is well-defined and analytic in $B(z_0,r)$.

I know what well-defined and analytic means but I just am really stumped as to how I am going to show this. Also, I don't quite understand what "which lies in the disk that extends from $z_0$ and $z$ is supposed to mean. Really sorry for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will write $\Gamma_z$ instead of $\Gamma(z)$; I think this alleviates the ambiguity of the notation.

**Well-defined**: note that you have infinitely many choices of contour $\Gamma_z$ for any $z$. Thus, you must show that for any choice of $\Gamma_z$, $f(z)$ has the same value.  Suppose you have two choices $\Gamma_z$ and $\tilde{\Gamma}_z$. If $f$ is well-defined, what can you say about the integral around the contour $\Gamma_z + (-\tilde{\Gamma}_z)$?

**Analytic**: show that $f$ is complex-differentiable. This is equivalent to analyticity.

Comment: Thank you! My question is assuming that it is well-defined, then the integral should be 0, hence the two contours are equal by the linearity of the integral. However, I'm not sure if this is the right way t show that it is well-defined since I already assumed it is well-defined at the start. Furthermore, how can I show that it is complex-differentiable? I tried cauchy-riemann but was left with nothing. Really sorry

Comment: @GabRomero You are correct that the integrals along the contours being equal is a necessary condition. However, it also happens to be a sufficient condition -- convince yourself that the reasoning used is, in this case, reversible. To show the function is complex-differentiable at say $w \in \mathbb{C}$, generally you want to consider $f(w)$ and how it compares to $f(w+h)$. Given a contour to $w$, what's a simple way to extend it to a contour to $w+h$ that might allow you to compute the derivative?

Comment: thank you so much for this, but I am still lost unfortunately. Can I ask for another hint with regards to how I'm going to be able to extend the contour to w + h? really sorry for my questions

Comment: @GabRomero Sorry for the late reply. Consider the line segment $[w,w+h]$ parametrised in any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

I agree this is ambiguous:

> take the contour $\Gamma(z)$, which lies in the disk that extends from $z_0$ to $z$.

The meaning is

> take the contour $\Gamma(z)$ such that $\Gamma(z)$ lies in the disk $B(z_0,r)$ and $\Gamma(z)$ extends from $z_0$ to $z$.

Comment: Thank you so much for that, will edit the question accordingly. Although I'm still unsure how to answer the problem, this helps me visualize it better.